# What's the purpose of the search; syntax?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I've stumbled on this code example for a web-worker :

```
search: while (true) {
  n++;
  for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++)
    if (n % i == 0)
      continue search;
  // found a prime!
  postMessage(n);
}
```

My question is, what is the purpose of the `search:` ? It does work without it and I couldn't find an explanation as to why it is there.

EDIT :
Okay thanks, I should have used my eyes instead of directly jumping to Google. It was a label used here : `continue search;`

Comment: Its a *label*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: defines which cycle to continue (`while` cycle in thid case)